# Problem linking libunity

Tags: application-development, development, programming, libunity, libdbusmenu

I'm trying to compile a basic C++ app consisting of the following code:

```
#include <unity/unity/unity.h>

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

just to try and get the `libunity` library compiled before I start doing any work on the app. I'm using QMake to manage the makefile, which is as follows:

```
######################################################################
# Automatically generated by qmake (2.01a) Mon Jan 2 16:33:26 2012
######################################################################

TEMPLATE = app 
TARGET = unity-lens-test

CONFIG -= qt

unix {
  CONFIG += link_pkgconfig
  PKGCONFIG += glib-2.0 
  PKGCONFIG += dee-1.0
  PKGCONFIG += libdbusmenu-0.4
}

LIBS += -lunity \
         += -lgtest

DEPENDPATH   += . src 

INCLUDEPATH  += .

# Input
SOURCES += src/main.cpp
```

My problem lies with the third `PKGCONFIG` directive within the `unix{}` block, referring to `libdbusmenu-0.4`. When I try to run `qmake` on this file, I get the following error:

```
Package libdbusmenu-0.4 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libdbusmenu-0.4.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'libdbusmenu-0.4' found
Package libdbusmenu-0.4 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libdbusmenu-0.4.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'libdbusmenu-0.4' found
Package libdbusmenu-0.4 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libdbusmenu-0.4.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'libdbusmenu-0.4' found
```

which is an error I never got when I added the entries for `glib-2,0` or `dee-1.0`. When I try to compile without this option, the `qmake` command succeeds but GCC returns the following error:

```
/usr/include/unity/unity/unity.h:15:37: fatal error: libdbusmenu-glib/client.h: No such file or directory
```

When I search for this file, I find it in

`/usr/include/libdbusmenu-0.4/libdbusmenu-glib/client.h`

in which case I would expect `PKGCONFIG += libdbusmenu-0.4` to fix the issue, at least going by my experience with the previous two options.

I have all the libunity build dependencies installed so I'm not sure what else I could possibly have to do to get this to compile. Is there something special about `libdbusmenu` that requires a different approach? Is the problem at my end? I've checked out the [Rocking out with libunity](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MeetingLogs/devweek1103/RockingOutwithlibunity) notes but there's nothing in there regarding compilation.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for the wrong package config file.  It should be `dbusmenu-glib-0.4`.

Answer (score 1):

install the following packages:

```
sudo apt-get install libdbusmenu-glib-dev
sudo apt-get install libunity-dev
```